# Finding the favorite from MySQL DB with several joins

Tags: mysql

I've spent days on this and it seems such a simple problem.  I'm hoping some kind soul can put me straight.

I have a database that contains information from recent horse races.  My question concerns 4 tables:

EVENTS,
RUNNERS,
COURSES,
PRICES

For a given meeting, e.g. Hereford on 4th Jan, I'm trying to return the bookies favorite to win each race.  I can produce the list of favorites and I can produce the details of each race, but I can't put them together.

So, this produces each favorite:

```
SELECT tbl_events.EVENT_ID, MIN(BSP)
from tbl_events
INNER JOIN tbl_prices ON tbl_prices.EVENT_ID = tbl_events.EVENT_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_courses ON tbl_courses.courseID = tbl_events.courseID
WHERE EVENT_DT LIKE '2017-01-04%'
AND place = "Here"
GROUP BY tbl_events.EVENT_ID;   

+-----------+----------+
| EVENT_ID  | MIN(BSP) |
+-----------+----------+
| 128981330 |     6.00 |
| 128981335 |     3.30 |
| 128981340 |     2.40 |
| 128981345 |     2.90 |
| 128981350 |     2.28 |
| 128981355 |     1.46 |
| 128981360 |     6.07 |
+-----------+----------+
```

and this produces all my other information:

```
SELECT tbl_events.EVENT_ID,tbl_events.EVENT_DT,country,place,SELECTION_NAME,  BSP
from tbl_events
INNER JOIN tbl_courses ON tbl_courses.courseID = tbl_events.courseID
INNER JOIN tbl_prices ON tbl_prices.EVENT_ID = tbl_events.EVENT_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_runners ON tbl_runners.runnersID = tbl_prices.runnersID
WHERE EVENT_DT LIKE '2017-01-04%'
AND place = "Here";

(LIMITED TO 10 just for illustration)

+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+---  -----+
| EVENT_ID  | EVENT_DT            | country | place | SELECTION_NAME    | BSP       |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+----  ----+
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Rainbow Haze      |   13.50 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Thats Gonna Sting |   7.37 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Raduis Bleu       | 124.38 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Staunton          |   6.00 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Tisfreetdream     | 111.71 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Flemi Two Toes    |  14.00 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Young Lou         |  14.76 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Act Four          |  25.00 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Late Shipment     |   7.23 |
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Celtic Tune       |  12.27 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+-------------------+--- -  ----+
```

What I can't do is put the two things together to produce the favorite for each event.  I've tried turning the first query into a sub query, I've tried various ways of joining the query to itself, I've tried embedding the first query as part of the where clause in the second query.

I've read pretty much every post I can find and looked at various tutorials.  There's lots of examples of returning minimum values for a group of records in the same table, but I just can't translate any of it into what I'm trying to do here by joining various tables.

Table creates (as requested) :

```
| tbl_events | CREATE TABLE `tbl_events` (
 `EVENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `EVENT_NAME` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
 `EVENT_DT` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `courseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`EVENT_ID`),
 KEY `courseID_idx` (`courseID`),
 CONSTRAINT `courseID` FOREIGN KEY (`courseID`) REFERENCES `tbl_courses`       (`courseID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| tbl_prices | CREATE TABLE `tbl_prices` (
`priceID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`EVENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`runnersID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`BSP` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
`PPMAX` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
`PPMIN` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
`IPMAX` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
`IPMIN` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
`MORNINGTRADEDVOLUME` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`PPTRADEDVOL` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
`IPTRADEDVOL` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`priceID`),
UNIQUE KEY `EVENTandRunnerIndex` (`EVENT_ID`,`runnersID`),
KEY `runnersID_idx3` (`runnersID`),
KEY `EVENT_ID_idx3` (`EVENT_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `EVENT_ID2` FOREIGN KEY (`EVENT_ID`) REFERENCES `tbl_events`      (`EVENT_ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `runnersID2` FOREIGN KEY (`runnersID`) REFERENCES `tbl_runners`   (`runnersID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
 )   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=747879 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| tbl_runners | CREATE TABLE `tbl_runners` (
`runnersID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`SELECTION_ID` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`SELECTION_NAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`EVENT_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`runnersID`),
UNIQUE KEY `SELECTION_NAME_UNIQUE` (`SELECTION_NAME`),
KEY `EVENT_ID_idx` (`EVENT_ID`)
)   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=749692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

| tbl_courses | CREATE TABLE `tbl_courses` (
`courseID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`country` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`place` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`courseID`),
UNIQUE KEY `uniquecourseINDEX` (`country`,`place`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=300620 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to test query without creation. You think you could add table creation or a link to sqlfiddle?

Comment: added as requested.

Answer (score 0):

OK, done a bit more work on this and I now have a model that works, based on a view which I then include in my subsequent query.  So,

```
ALTER VIEW favourites AS 
SELECT tbl_events.EVENT_ID, MIN(BSP) AS fav
FROM tbl_events
INNER JOIN tbl_prices ON tbl_events.EVENT_ID = tbl_prices.EVENT_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_courses ON tbl_courses.courseID = tbl_events.courseID
WHERE EVENT_DT LIKE '2017-01-04%'
AND place = 'Here'
GROUP BY tbl_events.EVENT_ID;
```

and then:

```
   SELECT tbl_events.EVENT_ID,tbl_events.EVENT_DT,country,place,SELECTION_NAME,  BSP
   from tbl_events 
   INNER JOIN tbl_courses ON tbl_courses.courseID = tbl_events.courseID
   INNER JOIN tbl_prices ON tbl_prices.EVENT_ID = tbl_events.EVENT_ID
   INNER JOIN tbl_runners ON tbl_runners.runnersID = tbl_prices.runnersID
   INNER JOIN favourites ON tbl_events.EVENT_ID = favourites.EVENT_ID AND     tbl_prices.BSP = favourites.fav
   where EVENT_DT LIKE '2017-01-04%'
   AND place = "Here"
   GROUP BY tbl_events.EVENT_ID;
```

Produces what I was looking for:

```
+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+----------------+------+
| EVENT_ID  | EVENT_DT            | country | place | SELECTION_NAME | BSP  |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+----------------+------+
| 128981330 | 2017-01-04 12:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Staunton       | 6.00  |
| 128981335 | 2017-01-04 13:25:00 | GB      | Here  | Canoodle       | 3.30 |
| 128981340 | 2017-01-04 13:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Charmix        | 2.40 |
| 128981345 | 2017-01-04 14:25:00 | GB      | Here  | Working Title  | 2.90 |
| 128981350 | 2017-01-04 14:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Jameson        | 2.28 |
| 128981355 | 2017-01-04 15:25:00 | GB      | Here  | Strong Pursuit | 1.46 |
| 128981360 | 2017-01-04 15:55:00 | GB      | Here  | Keel Haul      | 6.07 |
+-----------+---------------------+---------+-------+----------------+------+
```

How could I nest these two queries though to produce the end result in one shot ?